# Remove kubernetes deployment based on jsonnet file

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, jsonnet, kubeconfig

I am using jsonnet to describe deployment configuration for Kubernetes.

```
{
  apiVersion: 'apps/v1',
  kind: 'Deployment',
  metadata: {
    name: 'dapi-test-pod',
  },
  spec: {
    selector: {
      matchLabels: {
        app: 'dapi-test-pod',
      },
    },
    template: {
      metadata: {
        labels: {
          app: 'dapi-test-pod',
        },
      },
      spec: {
        containers: [
          {
            name: 'test-container',
            image: 'library/nginx',
          },
        ]
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Create deployment using kubecfg:

```
kubecfg show k8s/deployment.jsonnet | kubectl apply -f -
```

Everything is going well, but is there any great way to delete deployment using `kubecfg` and `jsonnet` file.

Comment: not get your quest. `kubectl delete` can delete it.

Comment: @BMW you are right, it seems I've missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario on my cluster and basically the same logic will works for deleting it.

```
kubecfg show k8s/deployment.jsonnet | kubectl delete -f -
```

This command will delete everything described in the manifest.

Or you can just delete using bare kubectl:

```
kubectl delete deployment dapi-test-pod
```

Comment: I am using the first way to delete the deployment, since the deployment name differs from the file name. But if I use `apply` after `delete` I receive this warning. As I understand warning is about mixing declarative and imperative ways. `Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply`

Comment: What you mean by using `apply` after `delete`? Please, can you update your question including the commands and outputs?

Comment: I found the article where everything is explained https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/object-management/#imperative-object-configuration